# Is it safe (XSS attacks) to provide callback functions in jQuery plugins?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, xss

I've been using a popular jQuery plugin for years and while reading about cyber security, which I'm certainly no expert but I'd like to learn how to write better code, I realised that this plugin and many more might be vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Can you please help me understand whether this plugin is safe?

Here's the simplified code (I won't mention the actual plugin...):

```
(function ($, document, window){
    var defaults = {
        callback: false,
        // more options
    };

    publicMethod = $.fn.pluginName = function (options, callback) {
        options = options || {};
        var settings = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, options);

        // event listener.
        trigger('pluginName.launch');
        
        // callback function.
        $.isFunction(settings.callback){
            settings.callback.call();
        }

        // more stuff
    };
};
}(jQuery, document, window));
```

So, you can call the plugin like this with a callback containing whatever code you like:

```
$.pluginName({
    option1: value1,
    callback: function(){
        $('#someDIV').html('<script>...</script>');
        $('body').append($('<script />...'));
        eval();// Do eval things...?
    }
});
```

And, you can add custom code to an event listener too...

```
$(document).on('pluginName.launch', function(){
    eval();// More eval stuff?
});
```

Is this a problem, since the user input is unsanatized JS?

I managed to execute a .call() in the Chrome console using the event listener and whatever code I fancied including. Seems sketchy to me.

```
var test = function(){
  alert('foo');
  //eval();....
}
    
$(document).on('pluginName.launch', function(){
    test.call();
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The XSS needs an attack vector. If the attacker can inject the code into the page from the URL or from something they managed to save in your database you will execute on someone else's browser, then it is vulnerable.

So if for example `yourpage?query='something you will show on the page'` can be linked, it can be changed to

`yourpage?query='<img onerror=\'loadSomethingHorrible()\' />'`

But if the only way you can hijack the callback is to use the console, then it is likely less vulnerable

Comment: Having read some more, I believe I’m barking up the DOM-based attack tree and not so much server-based.

The jQuery plugin I referenced also outputs “options” values to the page via jQuery .html(), which I’m lead to believe is “still executed as JavaScript when the element is evaluated”.

Keen to hear more thoughts on this

Comment: Possibly the options parameter can be polluted, but I do not see a direct danger